# jQuery outerheight : inefficient usage when trying to remove and add new div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I am trying to replace content of 1 div with another after calculating the height using outerHeight function.

Basically I am trying to replace mt facebook like box plugin with a sample image if the user is not logged on to facebook. (I am using over 21 authentication that's why the user won't be able to see like box plugin if he is not logged on to facebook and over 21)

I posted a similar question over here

[facebook like box: Showing sample image instead of feed when user is not logged in on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985810/facebook-like-box-showing-sample-image-instead-of-feed-when-user-is-not-logged)

Anyway, Here is my complete code.

HTML

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d, s, id) {

        var userLang = 'nl';
        var locale = '';
        if (userLang == 'nl') {
            locale = 'nl_NL';
        }
        else if (userLang == 'en') {
            locale = 'en_US';
        }
        else {
            locale = 'fr_FR';
        }

        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/" + locale + "/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=*********";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>


<div id="fsnMiddle" class="fbnl">
    <fb:like-box id="fbIframeBox" href="https://www.facebook.com/********" width="292" height="390" show_faces="true" colorscheme="dark" stream="false" show-border="false" header="false">
    </fb:like-box>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#fsnMiddle
{
    border: 1px solid #494949;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #202020;
    float: left;
    width: 290px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 14px 0 0;
}

#fsnMiddle #fbIframeBox
{

}

#fsnMiddle #fbReplacement
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 290px;
    height: 400px;
}
#fsnMiddle.fbfr #fbReplacement
{
    background-image: url('../../../cms/images/***.jpg');
    width: 290px;
    height: 400px;
}
#fsnMiddle.fbnl #fbReplacement
{
    background-image: url('../../../cms/images/***.jpg');
    width: 290px;
    height: 400px;
}
#fsnMiddle.fben #fbReplacement
{
    background-image: url('../../../cms/images/***.jpg');
    width: 290px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

JS

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var height = $("#fbIframeBox span").outerHeight(true);
    if (height == 0) {
        $('#fbIframeBox').remove();

        var fbReplacement = "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/***' id='fbReplacement' target='_blank'></a>" ;

        $('#fsnMiddle').append(fbReplacement);
    }
}, 2000);
```

Since the user is not logged in to facebook. So the outerHeight of facebook likebox (id = fbIframeBox) should be 0 on my website and the div fbIframeBox should be replaced by fbReplacement.

However the code is not working and i am not able to replace the div based on outerHewight.

It also throw me a warning Inefficient jQuery usage.

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Additional Info: I am testing on the local environment.

Comment: "The code is not working." Please elaborate.

Comment: Since I am not logged onto facebook the height of the likebox is 0 on my webpage. After comparing if height == 0 I am trying to replace the div fbIframeBox. My javascript snippet is not removing id fbIframeBox and replacing it with fbReplacement

Comment: Set a breakpoint on your `$("#fbIframeBox span")` selector. It returns `null` because there is no `span` descendant in your `#fbIframeBox` element. The content is not being replace because `null == 0` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @Desertivy can you please let me know how do I set a breakpoint.

Comment: Well I will use firebug and check out the query after setting breakpoints

Comment: In Firebug, go to the Script Tab. Using the dropdown, find the script you want to debug. You can set a breakpoint by clicking on a line number. Note that the code will not execute on this line until you step over to the next line, using the navigation buttons in the toolbar above your script. "Step In" will take you into a function call (if applicable), and "Step Out" will take you to the calling function. "Continue" will let the code execute until another breakpoint is hit.